# spacing in between components UIView from nib

Tags: iphone, ios

When I am placing two **UIbutton** vertically on **xib** the spacing in between them is doubled, when it is displayed in Retina 4 inch how to make equally spaced?. Is possible to achieve it without using Auto layout?

Comment: You have to provide button size programmetically in your .m file according to your iPhone Screen

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set two button's layout like this in your xib

.[image]

If you set like this, the gap between two buttons will be same as 3.5 inch screen(iPhone 4 & earlier).

Please let me know if you have any doubt in this.

Comment: yes the gap between the two buttons are almost same it works correctly but how this is helping it

Comment: IS your problem solved? Actually if you look at the image I attached, top enabled red mark ensures, that the button's y co-ordinate is always constant in all screen sizes.the same left red mark maintains the x co-ordinate constantly.

Comment: Even if u change the orientation also, these co-ordinates will be maintained constantly.

Comment: yeah thats wat i really need and i am also able to maintain the co-ordinates after orientation too thanks. it did.